# Need help using RANK in Excel (or MySql) for mulitple people, points scored

Tags: mysql, excel, ranking

I have a data set:

```
Player  Year    Points
John    2010    60
Jane    2010    83
Stan    2010    42
Brian   2010    51
Phil    2010    65
John    2009    1
Jane    2009    44
Stan    2009    89
Brian   2009    4
Phil    2009    82
John    2008    93
Jane    2008    12
Stan    2008    31
Brian   2008    41
Phil    2008    63
John    2007    47
Jane    2007    73
Stan    2007    72
Brian   2007    17
Phil    2007    81
```

I am looking to get the points and years ranked by PERSON, not overall. In other words:

```
Player  Year    Points  Personal Rank
John    2010    60  2
Jane    2010    83  1
Stan    2010    42  3
Brian   2010    51  1
Phil    2010    65  3
John    2009    1   4
Jane    2009    44  3
Stan    2009    89  1
Brian   2009    4   4
Phil    2009    82  1
John    2008    93  1
Jane    2008    12  4
Stan    2008    31  4
Brian   2008    41  2
Phil    2008    63  4
John    2007    47  3
Jane    2007    73  2
Stan    2007    72  2
Brian   2007    17  3
Phil    2007    81  2
```

Is this possible to do in Excel?

I also have this data in MySql if anyone knows (or can point me in the right direction) a SELECT for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excel has a function called precisely `RANK()`.

Comment: @Apalala Thanks, I know that. However, it only does the data set as a whole, not by individual person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set @player = '',@num=0;
select id,player,year,points,rank from
(select *, 
   @num := if(@player = player, @num + 1, 1) as rank,
   @player := player as p
from results order by player,points desc) as t
order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you could also use something like this:

```
SET @rank=0;

SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, person, year, points FROM yourtable ORDER BY id person;
```